# Should Hamas be treated like Amalek?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mitzvah, amalek

Do we say that Hamas's behaviour recently is as bad as Amalek, and therefore we have a mitzvah to completely eradicate them? If so, does that stretch to the whole of Gaza's population or even further?

I imagine that someone has written about this, possibly in the context of the Nazis. Has anyone seen anything?

Comment: in war halacha the enemy have the same status as amalek. See ספר תורת המלך

Comment: @KapinKrunch that's only in _milchamot mitzva_

Comment: @RabbiKaii Isn't that what this is?

Comment: @MosesSupposes perhaps that would be a good separate question. I think if we had a king it would be

Comment: @RabbiKaii do we need a king to declare a defensive war?

Comment: @MosesSupposes basic reading of Rambam would seem to imply that, but I have not delved deep into it. If you ask as a separate question, that might inspire me to do so, or rouse someone who knows to answer :) Just like we learn the halachos of yom tov during a yom tov, we might consider it relevant to study the halachos of war during war?

Comment: Does this conflict even meet the halachic definition of a war?

Comment: Also note that Hamas is not a nation that can be "completely eradicated". It is an organisation, which can be shut down for sure

Comment: דין הערבים בעזה הוא כדין עמלק וצריכים לקיים בהם מצוות מחיית עמלק, שהרי הם כתבו באמנת החמאס להשמיד כל יהודי, ומעשיהם בשמחת תורה, רציחת תינוקות וילדים באכזריות והשמדת כל יהודי שנקרה בדרכם, לימדו שהם שונאי ישראל. על כן יש מצווה להילחם בהם מלחמת חורמה ואסור לנהל איתם שום משא ומתן של שלום. הם הרשעה בהתגלמותה ואין השם שלם ואין הכיסא שלם עד שיימחה שמם ורשעתם מן העולם. 

https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/52638